# selectlist inside apex:column errors out

Tags: apex, selectlist, selectoption

I have a pageblock table with column as a selectlist, populated from controller. Here is the code:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="k" id="thePageBlockTable" rendered="{!records.size>0}">
    <apex:column headerValue="Choose">
          <apex:selectList value="{!k.Competitor_Product__c}"/>
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductNames}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
       </apex:column>
```

**controller:**

```
  public List<SelectOption> getProductNames()
    {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
      List<Product_vod_c__c> productlist =[Select Id,Product_Name__c FROM Product_vod_c__c];
      options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
      for (Integer j=0;j<productlist.size();j++)
      {
          options.add(new SelectOption(productlist[j].Product_Name__c,productlist[j].Product_Name__c));
      }
      return options;
    }
```

Gives error:

> **Error: inline1 line 38, column 9: The element type "apex:column" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""     Error:
>   The element type "apex:column" must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag "".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You terminate the `selectList` tag.

Replace :

```
<apex:selectList value="{!k.Competitor_Product__c}"/>
```

by :

```
<apex:selectList value="{!k.Competitor_Product__c}">
```